# calling javascript function from java in Codenameone

Tags: javascript, codenameone

**Update i clarified the question **
I am working on a Codenameone app with a local webpage. The webpage is a local html file and a bundle of javascript files. The webpage is loaded in the webbrowsercomponent (bc). i like to call this javascript functions directly from codenameone. I first used bc.postmessage. But i noticed that the message queue is not disposed after sending the message. I am now looking at the bc.execute method in Codenameone.But i can't figure out with codenameone documentation how i must do that.

i have in javascript the function setLocation(dat). With that function i populate a htmltable with location data.

How do i sent the information to the function from within java with bc.execute. What is the proper code?
bc.execute("setgpsdata( ${0} }), result); is wrong. i got a error message in netbeans ; no suitable method for execute

```
public void locationUpdated(Location loc) {
         
         locationReady=true;
                try {   
                      
                 loc = Im.getCurrentLocation();
            
        
                 float Direction =  loc.getDirection();
 
                  float acc =   loc.getAccuracy();
                  double latp = loc.getLatitude();
                  double lonp = loc.getLongitude();
                  double speed = loc.getVelocity();
                  
           
        
    
          double speedo = 3.6 * speed;
          double roundspd = MathUtil.round(speedo *10);
          roundspd = roundspd/10;

          
  
          String result = cde+ String.valueOf( roundspd) + ","+ String.valueOf(Direction) + ","+ String.valueOf(acc) + ","+ String.valueOf(latp) + "," +String.valueOf(lonp); 


          
          
         //  bc.postMessage(result.toString(), "*");;   
                  
            String js = "setgpsdata( ${0} })"; 

            bc.execute("setgpsdata( ${0} }), result);
             
                } catch (IOException e) {
             
                   Dialog.show("GPS error4", "Your location could not be found, please try going outside for a better GPS signal", "Ok", null);
                }
            
             

        }
```

On the javascript side:

```
function setgpsdata(dat) {
var dat = [];
dat = data.split(",");
var speed = dat[0];
var heading = dat[1];
var acc = dat[2];
var latwp = dat[3];
var lonwp = dat[4];


var myTable2 = document.getElementById("GPSdata");
myTable2.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML = speed + ' [km/h]';
myTable2.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML = heading;
myTable2.rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML = acc + ' [m]';
myTable2.rows[3].cells[1].innerHTML = latTostring(latwp);
myTable2.rows[4].cells[1].innerHTML = lonTostring(lonwp);
```

}

Comment: You can open http://localhost:8088/ in chrome to see the errors in JavaScript when something fails. This code doesn't seem to be correct, what's `setgps(${0})`, shouldn't it be in quotes? What's cde? I'm missing some context here.

Comment: @Shai Almog i updated the question

Comment: OK. You're still missing a double quote in the execute call and aren't using the `js` variable. I guess those are typos?  Do you see an error in the JS console in chrome? Is it possible the HTML isn't fully loaded yet? We can't execute JS before the onLoad event was invoked from the browser so is the browser in loaded state.

Comment: Thanx Shai , it were the typo errors. I notice now that it is the same method als calling a javascript function in webview2 environment

Answer (score 2):

Pass String result directly to bc execute function

```
bc.execute("setgpsdata('" + result + "')");
```

See this

https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/

[BrowserComponent Demo](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Ant/blob/c08e38e265a8091d2bbbe4d2db86392ff031d308/src/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/advft/JSFt.java#L89-L114)

See also in "JavaScript Interaction" menu of this app

[FeaturesCN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomuhtech.cn.features)