# Codename one and javascript (share screen)

Tags: javascript, callback, codenameone

I have an android app developed in java with Codename One. Everything that is displayed on the screen belongs to a BrowserComponent that opens a url mydomain.com to which I have access.

**I need the user to be able to share a checkout screen in my html.**

I tried to take a screenshot but can't get "browser.addJSCallback" to work

```
browser.addJSCallback(
    "document.getElementById('shareBtn').addEventListener('click', function(){callback.onSuccess(true)})",
    res -> {
        System.out.println(res);
        takeScreenShot();
    }
);
```

and HTML

```
<html>
<button id='shareBtn'>Share</button>    
<script></script>
</html>
```

In the above case, the " System.out.println(res);" is not even executed. Taking a screenshot is the method I thought of, but I wonder if there is a better, more optimal way to do it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Share** Menu of this [FeaturesCN](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zomuhtech.cn.features) app and [this implementation](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Maven/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/advft/ShareFt.java) demonstrates screenshot sharing. You can try it.

Comment: It's exactly what I needed, it works! Thank you very much Eric!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing there's an error in the JavaScript which you can see in the chrome debugging tools. Just navigate to http://localhost:8088/ and debug the failure.

However, I don't think the screenshot code will work. OSs block screenshots of web browsers for security reasons (stealing user information, etc.). Screenshots of the app itself will work easily but the browser is a bit problematic.

Comment: Thanks. If I can't capture I'll have to look for another option, but I'll need to be able to communicate Codename One with Javascript. I have done everything that says https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676540/codename-one-javascript-callback

I have not been successful. Do you know any simple example that can help me?

Comment: You can pass data from Codename One to JavaScript [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009660/calling-javascript-function-from-java-in-codenameone/76020565#76020565)